# A problem with user registeriation. Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a problem using node js and mongo db with sign up route. When I use Insomnia to post data it returns error: [Here is what it returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnGAv.png)

Here is my code:

```
    const express     = require('express'),
      app         = express(),
      bodyParser  = require('body-parser'),
      mongoose    = require('mongoose'),
      jwt       = require('jsonwebtoken'),
      bcrypt    = require('bcrypt'),
      config    = require('./config'),
      User      = require('./models/user');

//MongoDb configuration
mongoose.connect(config.db, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Mongo is here for you!');
  }
});

//BodyParser configuration
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//Routes
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.json({
    "message": "Welcome to the Node express api!"
  });
});

//SignUp
app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {

  var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8);

  User.create({
    email : req.body.email,
    password : hashedPassword
  },

  function (err, user) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem registering the user.")
    // create a token
    var token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, config.secret, {
      expiresIn: config.tokenTime // expires in
    });
    res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });
  });
});

//Show all users
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.json(users);
  });
});


// SERVERHOST
app.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('Node api server has started! :)');
});
```

> And here is mongoDb model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const user = mongoose.Schema({
   email: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   },
   password: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', user);
```

Maybe you had some kind of simular error. Please help me to find out the reason of this problem. This code worked once and I registered one user in db, but after that it is returns only such kind of mistake. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try checking what the `err` actually is? Might help narrow it down

Comment: You need to check what `err` is from `User.create()` function.

Comment: Thank you both Ankit and CertainPerformance! You helped me a lot! I find out what the error it was and it solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in ""errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error index", means that the issue was in data base. I just updated the schema with username and deleted old data.